# Who writes header files

Tags: c, header-files

We have been learning C and it might seem like a stupid question to ask. 
I want to know who exactly writes header files. I know that they have predefined functions in them and can be accessed as per need.

Comment: your question is basically who writes code? programmers! (except the files that were auto generated)

Comment: But aren't these like standard files? So am I safe to say that if a version of a compiler is upgraded they may have added new functions?

Comment: also can these header files by altered by users?

Comment: Some of the headers are language-standard (like `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h`).  Yes, they might change with a new version of a compiler or C library.  It would be a bad idea to try modifying those yourself.  Others are headers for your own code, which you can change however and whenever you want.

Comment: I think the question should be reversed, "Who doesn't write header files?",...

Answer (score 18):

The header files that come with your compiler are written by the authors of your compiler and C library.  Header files for third-party libraries are written by the authors of those libraries.  Header files for your software are written by you.

Answer (score 2):

Header files are written by the programmers to export the library functions or class. Header files may used to define classes, macros , member functions,  structures, variables etc. if you make some changes in header files of your library it may affect your library functions. You have to recompile the library before use.